# Subscribe to all changes with detailed info

Tags: xamarin, realm

It is critical for us to track all changes with detailed information: operation type (create, update or delete), object type, the changed object (or its PKs, if there is), and what properties changed.

Is there a way to do this? A workaround? We are blocked with this. Using Xamarin.iOS.

Hope someone can help us. Thanks!

Comment: For collections look at `SubscribeForNotifications` for create/change/delete indexes, for an individual `RealmObject`,  add a `PropertyChangedEvent` handler to the object. You can always embed your RealmObject subclasses within a higher level model (a datamanager) and have that abstracted model track all the changes via SubscribeForNotifications/PropertyChangedEvent for each `RealmObject` and `IRealmCollection` that are requested.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for your quick answer. I'm aware of these subscription methods, but having to iterate through all retrieved `RealmObject`s and subscribe to their changes in order to get also the changed properties felt clumsy to me, risking also to subscribe twice for the same entity, but correct me if I'm wrong. I was expecting maybe something more like `realm.RealmChanged += (s, e) => { }` but getting more detailed data, such as the object, the operation and the changed property names (in case of an update). Thanks!!

Comment: As you seen `RealmChanged` does not provide that level of detail, that level of detail is currently reserved for use within the `Mobile Platform` product. You can construct a data manager / data model that implements full change logging by constructing a `undo/redo model` and via interfaces that expose a level of model properties that in turn connect to the "hidden" RealmObject properties (same for RealmCollections) and thus you "see" all data changes. I did this for a client before the Mobile Platform was first announced as the app had HIPAA requirements and remote sync requirements.

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way. I thought about doing like a proxy that connects to the realm obj to “intercept” changes, but I’m not sure. I was rethinking the data layer of an existing app (also with remote sync reqs). It uses a lot of joins and felt like sqlite was falling short, so I started considering Realm, but I’m seeing that has a big impact on the app: check threading everywhere, add updates write transactions, async await is discouraged now, can’t track changes easily, etc. I’m considering mapping realm objects to models now, but all realm pros are gone doing this, except joins

Comment: IMHO: It really depends upon your app requirements, Realm is "just" one item in a toolset and Sqlite definitely has its place. (SQL is king and well know and Realm only supports a subset of Linq). Choose what works for your app. I written "large" Realm apps (including one that only runs on iPad Pros). The problems you noted that you would be losing can be avoided, but it requires code, time and knowledge. I use a Viper architecture with Realm/Xamarin and can avoid losing its *cool* features but my knowledge of Realm within a Martin-based clean architecture did not come easy at all, hahahaha

Comment: Thank you for your valuable insights @SushiHangover. I let you know what I did when I come to a consensus.

Comment: We finally decided to stick with sqlite-net, but we added a new thin layer on top of our data layer: a memory cache for a subset of the most used objects (mainly for joins) in the app. We did a quick test and measurements are over x10 faster in some cases, the memory cache does not take too much to load (less than 100ms worst case) and it does not consume a lot of memory. Maybe it's not the best solution, but it has almost zero impact on the rest of the application and exceeded our performance expectations on the tests. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe for changes of specific db table with

```
IDisposable sidesSubscription = Realm.GetInstance().All<Side>()
                                .SubscribeForNotifications(OnSidesChanged);

private void OnSidesChanged(IRealmCollection<Side> sender, ChangeSet changes, Exception error)
{
   //handle changes
}
```

Notice that you will need to do it on a thread with looper (like UI thread) or call `Realm.Refresh()` on the thread that created `Realm.GetInstance().All<Side>()` collection in order to get `OnSidesChanged` called.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. With your solution I don't see how to get the modified properties if an object is being updated... :\

Comment: there is no intended way to get the modified properties. At best you can subscribe for notifications of changes of specific object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer